# Same field being used as main table attribute and GSI Hash Key

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I'm modeling a visits tracking system in Amazon's DynamoDB. The model is the following:

1. There are QR's in places, and Users
2. A user can visit a place, scan the QR to record a visit, hence storing in a separate table a (QRId, UserId, Timestamp, EventType) event.
3. For the access pattern I need querying by userId, QRId, and filtering by timestamp.

So far, my design of the GSI tables looks like this:

```
{
  "AttributeDefinitions": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "timestamp",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "qr-id",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "user-id",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    }
  ],
  "TableName": "qr_events",
  "KeySchema": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "qr-id",
      "KeyType": "HASH"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "timestamp",
      "KeyType": "RANGE"
    }
  ],
  "ProvisionedThroughput": {
    "ReadCapacityUnits": 10,
    "WriteCapacityUnits": 10
  },
  "GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
    {
      "IndexName": "qr_events_by_user",
      "KeySchema": [
        {
          "AttributeName": "user-id",
          "KeyType": "HASH"
        },
        {
          "AttributeName": "timestamp",
          "KeyType": "RANGE"
        }
      ],
      "Projection": {
        "ProjectionType": "ALL"
      },
      "ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 10,
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 10
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My problem is the following: After I load some new QRs and some visit events to Dynamo (using a 
 Spring-Boot API), when I query directly the table for some events with a QRId of 123 (for example), and the timestamp between two dates, all the results come back without the user-id attribute.

```
[{'type': 'IN', 'qr-id': 'd50e97c3-86f4-4393-bf5b-7564f7d39099', 'timestamp': '2020-05-30T00:11:27.621Z'}]
```

I'm doing my queries with boto3, as in the following script:

```
    def get_visits_for_qr_between_dates(self, qr_id: str, from_time: datetime.datetime, to_time: datetime.datetime):
        key_expression = Key('qr-id').eq(qr_id) & \
                         Key('timestamp').between(from_time.isoformat(), to_time.isoformat())

        response = self.table.query(
            KeyConditionExpression=key_expression
        )

        return response['Items']
```

Is there some kind of restriction of not projecting the GSI hash index into the table?